# How to use elasticsearch and connect it to react search component

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I build a knowledge base website and it has search component, cards, and filters. I just want to use elasticsearch and connect it to the search component so when I search it give autocomplete or suggestions and map only the cards that match it.

The problem is how to build it? I search a lot didn't find any friendly-bignner tutorials for react.js and elasticsearch. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As ElasticSearch docs says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html), there are some clients for Elastic Search:

> Java REST Client [7.14]
>
> JavaScript API [7.x]
>
> Ruby API [7.x]
>
> Go API [7.x]
>
> .NET API [7.x]
>
> PHP API [7.x]
>
> Perl API
>
> Python API [7.x]
>
> eland
>
> Rust API
>
> Java API (deprecated) [7.14]
>
> Community Contributed Clients

So you need:

1. To have a back end (the above list) to talk with ElasticSearch.
2. Your back end will talk with front end - your ReactJS application

E.g.: It is possible to have ASP.NET WEB API which uses ElasticSearch. And ReactJS will communicate with back end to show data.